Axum with_state API error: Expected MethodRouter<()>, found MethodRouter<AppState>
I'm working on an Axum project and encountering an issue when using the with_state API. My goal is to provide an application state (AppState) to the handlers in my Axum router, but I keep getting the following error:
note: expected struct MethodRouter<()>
found struct MethodRouter<AppState>
Here's the structure of my project:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    if let Ok(db) = init_db().await {
        let state = state::app_state::AppState::new(db);
        let routes = routes::root::routes();
        let router = Router::new().with_state(state).nest("/api", routes);
        let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3000").await.unwrap();
        axum::serve(listener, router).await.unwrap();
    }
}

root.rs
pub fn routes() -> Router {
    Router::new().merge(user_routes())
}

routes/user.rs
pub fn routes() -> Router {
    Router::new().route("/auth/register", post(register_user))
}

handler/user.rs
pub async fn register_user(Json(payload): Json<User>, State(state): State<AppState>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    ...
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct AppState {
    db_conn: Database
}

impl AppState {
    pub fn new(db: Database) -> AppState {
        AppState {
            db_conn: db
        }
    }
}

The error suggests a type mismatch between MethodRouter<()> and MethodRouter, and I suspect the issue may lie with how I'm setting up my routes or merging them in root.rs. Any suggestions for resolving this?
What I’ve Tried:
I've tried different configurations with with_state and nest, but the error persists. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Please remove anything that's not required to reproduce the issue and add anything that's required to reproduce it. I.e. what are the modules handler, dto, utils, routes, ... what of them is really required, remove anything that's not, add definitions for all functions/methods/types that are.  In other words please [edit] your question to include a [mre] within the post, not as an external link.

What's init_db what's state::app_state::AppState, ... please don't just remove all the mod statementes, you have to define everything that you use which is not publicly available.

I have updated the question. AppState is the struct which holds db connection

If I use with_state in this way, it requires the tuple to be passed. let router = Router::new().nest("/api", routes).with_state(()); I have no idea why

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module state
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module routes
error[E0425]: cannot find function init_db in this scope
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type Router Please make sure your example is a [mre] i.e. we can copy the code you provided and compile it to see the same error, not a bunch of undefined symbols errors.

IIRC, you have to put .with_state(...) after the routes that use the state.
